# trying to convert csv to xml , one xml file should get generated for each 15 records present in csv file

Tags: python

I am new to python family I am trying to convert csv to xml in my python code,

Comment: Have you written any code? Have you encountered any errors? We can't simply write that code for you. Please see [ask]

Comment: yes, I have written code, in that I have generated one single xml file with all csv file records

Comment: actually I have done that part, need help other than that @rzlvmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading your input file in chunks and convert each chunk to `xml` iteratively. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 15

def convert_xml(df):
    Row_list =[]
    # Iterate over each row
    for index, rows in df.iterrows():
        # Create list for the current row
        my_list =[rows.col_1, rows.col_2]
        # append the list to the final list
        Row_list.append(my_list)
    with open('path/to/output/file', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(convert_row(record) for record in Row_list))

for chunk in pd.read_csv('path/to/file', chunksize=chunksize):
    convert_xml(chunk)
```

replace `col_1` and `col_2` with headers in your csv file.

Cheers!!

Comment: thank you brother for reply, but I have tried this but then how to convert dataframe to xml

Comment: @Ganesh Check now. I have added the corresponding code. Basically, open the chunk -> write rows in that chunk to list -> convert list to xml -> repeat for every chunk. Do upvote if this helps.

Comment: Brother, I have csv file 
col_1,col_2
1,101
2,102
.... 
100,200 and currently I am getting last 10 records in generated XML  file         <AllData>                                                                                   
<first_clm>91</first_clm>
<second_clm>191</second_clm>
</AllData>
....
<AllData>                                                                                 
<first_clm>100</first_clm>                                           
<second_clm>200</second_clm>
</AllData>

Answer (score 0):

If I undesrtand correctly, your code is working correctly but you have only one XML file with last chunk info.

It happens because you loop over chunks and rewrite `result.xml` at every iteration.

Just change file name for every chunk:

```
...

def convert_xml(df, file_name):

    ...
    
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
       f.write(...)

idx = 1
for chunk in csv_file:
    convert_xml(chunk, f'result_{idx}.xml')
    idx += 1
```